# System.BadImageFormatException when use C# call C++

Tags: c#, c++, dll

code is here https://github.com/Layty/cppnetdll

I have check the cpp dll and c# all is on x86, my pc is x64 ,I have also use both cpp and C# with x64
but it still tell me like

```
Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'DLLMYX86, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. 试图加载格式不正确的程序。
File name: 'DLLMYX86, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' ---> System.BadImageFormatException: 试图加载格式不正确的程序。 (0x8007000B)
   at MYNETX86.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Comment: Instead of linking to a GitHub, could you post the code that is throwing the error for people to read? It's easier than downloading and searching through a whole project. Also explain what it is your hoping to achieve with the code that is throwing the error, your much more likely to get an answer this way.

Comment: A c# application is managed code and c++ code must be run in unmanaged space.  How are you assigned the c++ memory space?

Answer (score 0):

Your native dll is referenced as a regular managed dll. This will not work. Your options are

1. Rewrite the functionality in managed code
2. Use [C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170) to produce a managed dll
3. Use [PInvoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/pinvoke) to call a native dll

I would prefer option 1 if possible. Interacting with unmanaged code is kind of a pain in the ass for anything except the most trivial signatures.

Answer (score 0):

In .NET when you compile a managed assembly the compiler generate a intermediate code which is then compile at the fly by the JIT (just in time compiler) for the machine architecture where you are running your application.

A native (C++) dll is compiled for a specific architecture (could be x86 or x64) and the binary image file is specific for that architecture.

If you want to use a native dll from a .NET app you have to be sure that the JIT compiles the code for the same architecture the native dll was made for. The only way to be sure that everything is coherent is to compile the .NET assembly for that specific architecture. In Visual Studio this is possible switching the target architecture from Any CPU to the same of the native dll.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# project targets .Net Core 3.1, so you need update your C++ project to target the same version.

In Project Properties > Advanced > C++/CLI Properties.

1. Set **Common Language Runtime Support** to `.Net Core Runtime Support (/clr:netcore)`, then click **Apply**.
2. Set **.Net Target Framework Version** to `netcoreapp3.1` or `.NET Core 3.1`.

Comment: I am new  in c# , My pc just have one net version I think

Answer (score 0):

I have solve this problem. I remove the pch.h and the pch.cpp  and dllmain , then every thing run well .

But I dont know why ? it is just pre combile , and I have clean obj dir and clean project befor .

Comment: sorry, just remove function `DllMain`, every thing is ok

Comment: Please edit your answer rather than adding a comment to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have update my git code . just fix  https://github.com/Layty/cppnetdll/blob/master/DLLMYX86/DLLMYX86/dllmain.cpp
or del this file.

I have make  other  both include cpp and C# .

othrs if have problem can download it. it works well

now I can new cpp object in c#