# Call nested .NET dll from C++/CLI Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, c++-cli

I'm trying to call a DLL-method from my C++/CLI code in Visual Studio a .NET-DLL (v4.5) called "LicenseCheck.dll". This works fine until this DLL is trying to access another .NET-DLL called "SKCLNET.dll" (.NET v1.0.3705). Meaning the "LicenseCheck.dll" depends on "SKCLNET.dll".

When I try to call the Licensecheck.dll-method "ValidateLicense::GetLicenseStatus()" from a .NET-project it all works fine.

Here is the error I get when running the C++/CLI code:

> Unhandled Exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly
> 'SKCLNET.dll' or one of its dependencies.  is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception
> from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)
> at Seat.Core.LicenseProvider..ctor()
> at Seat.Core.LicenseProvider.get_Instance()
> at LicenseCheck.ValidateLicense.GetLicenseStatus()
> at main(String[] args) in C:\Users\deckenf\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.cpp:line 13
> at mainCRTStartupStrArray(String[] arguments) in
> D:\a_work\1\s\src\vctools\crt\crtw32\msilcrt\mcrtexe.cpp:line 241
> C:\Users\deckenf\Desktop\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe
> (process 33364) exited with code -532462766.

Here the structure of the used dll:

[image]

Here the ValidateLicense class in the .NET dll with the function GetLicenseStatus(). This function is being invoked by C++/CLI.

```
    public static class ValidateLicense
{
    public static string GetLicenseStatus()
    {
        return LicenseProvider.Instance.CheckLicense().ToString();
    }
}
```

Here some more details of the SKCLNET assembly:

[image]

Comment: [I downvoted because an image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: In your first paragraph you mention LicenseCheck.dll several times. Didn't you mean SKCLNET.dll at least in some of them ? Also can you show the structure of the SKCLNET.dll ? (your screenshot shows only LicenseCheck.dll).

Comment: BTW - About showing code etc. as images, see here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors.

Comment: `System.BadImageFormatException` are 80 % of the time due to 32/64 bit problems. Check that your application is running the same "bittnes" as the library.

Comment: In Project Properties > Advanced > C++/CLI Properties. Set Common Language Runtime Support, This might fix it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72628522/system-badimageformatexception-when-use-c-sharp-call-c

Comment: Ok got it with the picture of code and deleted the picture.
@wohlstand I edit first paragraph, you were right.
When I run the application with x86 it gives me an other error...
Seems that the LicenseCheck.sll is x64 and SKCLNET.dll is x86. But as I mentioned in questio, it woks when I run it in a .NET project with x64

Comment: @wohlstand: Please see updated SKCLNET.dll structure screenshot

Comment: When I run a Windows form application the error disappears when I check mark in the solution properties --> Build --> General --> Prefer 32-bit.

If this parameter is unchecked then I get the same error as in the C++CLR project.
Does anyone know how I can set this parameter in the C++CLR project? The property options are quite different.

Comment: You keep calling SKCLNET.dll an "embedded" dll. What does that even mean? If it is a managed assembly, what architecture is it built for?

Comment: The naming "embedded" is obviously misleading, so I edited it in the question.
I prefer to build it for x86 architecture, because it could also run on x64 architecture due to backward compatibility as I understood - correct me, if I'm wrong.

Comment: You have to build a mixed-mode C++/CLI project to target either Win32 or x64, since unmanaged code has to be compiled to the proper platform. Open "Configuration Manager" in VS and verify the correct target platform.

Comment: "ConsoleApplication1\x64\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe" gives a strong hint you are running a 64-bit build of the .exe file.  And clearly SKCLNET requires a 32-bit process.  Kaboom.  If the .exe project is a C# project then use Project > Properties > Build tab, prefer 32-bit checked.  Repeat for the Release configuration.

Comment: @Hans Passant, you were right. I did some research in the morning on how to setup the platform targets properly for my C++/CLI project. After building the C++/CLI project for 32-bit the following error apperears (I also set in App.config the "useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy" = true, because this helped to make it run in the C# project):
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException: Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v1.0.3705' of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional configuration information.

Comment: Why do I get this error in my C++/CLI project but not in C# project?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After two days of investigation, I finally found the problem.
As @Hans Passant worte in the comments, the error in the question is caused because I built the .exe against 64-bit even though SKCLNET.dll requires 32-bit process.

Due to SKCLNET.dll targets .NET v1.0.3705 it was also necessary to add a app.config file to the C++/CLI project and add the `useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy`-tag. It is a configuration option in .NET Framework that is used to control the runtime activation policy for applications that use mixed-mode assemblies. In .NET Framework 4 and later versions, the runtime activation policy was changed to a new default behavior. This default behavior can cause some older applications that were designed to work with earlier versions of the .NET Framework to fail.

The last important step was to copy this app.config file after the build in the target path. To do this right click on the C++/CLI project > Properties > Build -Events > Post-Build Event and for the `Command Line` parameter you paste the following line:

`copy app.config "$(TargetPath).config"`

[image: Picture shows how to automate copying the app.config file to target path.]

This [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21036/Working-with-Configuration-Files-app-config-in-C-C) was helpful to solve my issue.